# FactoryGirl - ArgumentError: Factory not registered:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

When run poll_spec.rb, error - ArgumentError: Factory not registered: vote_option

factories.rb:

```
   FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email "mail@mail.com"
    password "foobarrr"
    password_confirmation "foobarrr"
  end

  factory :poll do
    topic "What your name?"

    trait :vote_option1 do
      association :vote_option, title: "Dima"
    end

    trait :vote_option2 do
      association :vote_option, title: "Sasha"
    end
  end
end
```

Its my test file poll_spec.rb:

```
  require 'rails_helper'


RSpec.describe Poll, type: :model do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  #subject { @poll }

  #it { should respond_to(:topic) }
  #it {should be_valid}


  describe "wrong information" do
    describe "less than or equal 1 vote option" do
      before do
        FactoryGirl.create(:poll, :vote_option1)

      end

      it { should_not be_valid }
    end
  end

end
```

Its gem file:
    ...........................
    group :test do
      gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4.4'
      gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.46.2'
      gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.5.0'
    end

How me fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the factory for vote_option.
You need to create a factory vote_option:

```
factory :vote_option do
  title "test"
end
```

Then you have the missing factory.
Now youre poll factory can look like this:

```
factory :poll do
  topic "What your name?"
  vote_option
end
```

Comment: thank you, Robbert. But now showwing error in poll_spec.rb Failure/Error: @poll = FactoryGirl.create(:poll, :vote_option1)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `vote_option=' for #<Poll:0xc926984>

Comment: Yeah maybe thats because you want a association. Maybe you can try this: Keep the factory :vote_option and make youre poll factory like this: factory :poll do vote_option end. This way the association is linked. You can still define youre own vote_option you just need to overwrite it when you create the poll factory. Let me know if it's works